# Access database Date type mismatch

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
'Sql = "Select ItemName,Count(itemID) from tblItem where Item ='" & "A" & "' AND ExpireDate < '" & Now().Date() & "' Group By ItemName"
```

I'm FACING Datatype miss match in this query in DATE Field....

How could I do this?

Comment: How does your post relate at all to the title?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape your date with the pound "#" symbol.

Try this:

```
"Select ItemName,Count(itemID) from tblItem where Item ='" & "A" & "' AND ExpireDate < #" & Now().Date() & "# Group By ItemName"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter with current date in MS Access just use `Date`. In where clause date should be surrounded by `#` sign

```
 SQL = "Select ItemName,Count(itemID) from tblItem where Item ='" & "A" & "' AND ExpireDate < #" & Date & "# Group By ItemName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Date()* function of Access:

```
Sql = "Select ItemName, Count(itemID) From tblItem Where Item ='A' And ExpireDate < Date() Group By ItemName"
```